# Get the google docs api refresh token and access token using Asp.Net MVc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-api, google-docs-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Can anyone help me to get the google docs api refresh token for the first time in asp .Net MVC. I have client Id and Client Secrete, from this how should i get the refresh token and further from refresh token how should i get the access token to access the google api for drive.

Comment: Which version of the google docs api have you looked into?

Comment: i used google api v3.

Comment: I am still assuming you mean Google Drive API as Google docs API isn't actually a thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They haven't done a lot of with the sample code for the [Drive API V3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/) yet have they.    I wouldn't use all of these scopes pick which ones you need this code is pre-generated.

NuGet Package

> PM>  [Install-Package Google.Apis.Drive.v3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Drive.v3/)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This method requests Authentication from a user using Oauth2.  
    /// Credentials are stored in System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal
    /// Documentation https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="clientSecretJson">Path to the client secret json file from Google Developers console.</param>
    /// <param name="userName">Identifying string for the user who is being authentcated.</param>
    /// <returns>DriveService used to make requests against the Drive API</returns>
    public static DriveService AuthenticateOauth(string clientSecretJson, string userName)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
                throw new Exception("userName is required.");
            if (!File.Exists(clientSecretJson))
                throw new Exception("clientSecretJson file does not exist.");

            // These are the scopes of permissions you need. It is best to request only what you need and not all of them
            string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,                   // View and manage the files in your Google Drive
                                             DriveService.Scope.DriveAppdata,            // View and manage its own configuration data in your Google Drive
                                             DriveService.Scope.DriveFile,               // View and manage Google Drive files and folders that you have opened or created with this app
                                             DriveService.Scope.DriveMetadata,           // View and manage metadata of files in your Google Drive
                                             DriveService.Scope.DriveMetadataReadonly,   // View metadata for files in your Google Drive
                                             DriveService.Scope.DrivePhotosReadonly,     // View the photos, videos and albums in your Google Photos
                                             DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly,           // View the files in your Google Drive
                                             DriveService.Scope.DriveScripts};           // Modify your Google Apps Script scripts' behavior
            UserCredential credential;
            using (var stream = new FileStream(clientSecretJson, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/apiName");

                // Requesting Authentication or loading previously stored authentication for userName
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                                                                         scopes,
                                                                         userName,
                                                                         CancellationToken.None,
                                                                         new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            }

            // Create Drive API service.
            return new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "Drive Authentication Sample",
                });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Create Oauth2 DriveService failed" + ex.Message);
            throw new Exception("CreateOauth2DriveFailed", ex);
        }
    }
```

Service account Json key file not the p12

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Authenticating to Google using a Service account
    /// Documentation: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#serviceaccount
    /// 
    /// Note: Not all APIs support service accounts I cant garentee this will work.   If you find an api that doesnt support service accoutns contact me 
    ///       me at www.daimto.com and I will remove it from auto genration of this APIs sample project.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serviceAccountEmail">From Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com</param>
    /// <param name="serviceAccountCredentialFilePath">Location of the Json Service account key file downloaded from Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com</param>
    /// <returns>DriveService used to make requests against the Drive API</returns>
    public static DriveService AuthenticateServiceAccount(string serviceAccountCredentialFilePath)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath))
                throw new Exception("Path to the .JSon service account credentials file is required.");
            if (!File.Exists(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath))
                throw new Exception("The service account credentials .JSon file does not exist at:" + serviceAccountCredentialFilePath);

            // These are the scopes of permissions you need. It is best to request only what you need and not all of them
            string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,                   // View and manage the files in your Google Drive
                                             DriveService.Scope.DriveAppdata,            // View and manage its own configuration data in your Google Drive
                                             DriveService.Scope.DriveFile,               // View and manage Google Drive files and folders that you have opened or created with this app
                                             DriveService.Scope.DriveMetadata,           // View and manage metadata of files in your Google Drive
                                             DriveService.Scope.DriveMetadataReadonly,   // View metadata for files in your Google Drive
                                             DriveService.Scope.DrivePhotosReadonly,     // View the photos, videos and albums in your Google Photos
                                             DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly,           // View the files in your Google Drive
                                             DriveService.Scope.DriveScripts};           // Modify your Google Apps Script scripts' behavior
            Stream stream = new FileStream(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            var credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped(scopes);

            // Create the  Drive service.
            return new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "Drive Authentication Sample",
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Create service account DriveService failed" + ex.Message);
            throw new Exception("CreateServiceAccountDriveServiceFailed", ex);
        }
    }
```

Let me know if you need anything else I have a partial sample project built.

Comment: Thanks a lot DalmTo . I got the UserCredential and DriveService successfully.Can you please let me know it is possible that my site visitor can upload files to my google drive and i will authorize the oauth in background i.e currently it ask for login. So how can i achieve this?

Comment: if you want to let people upload to your account. You should consider using a service account instead of Oauth2.   Then you can share the folder on your drive account with the service account.  Service accounts are kind of dummy users then the service account can upload to the drive folder just remember that the service account will need to update the permissions on the file to give you permissions to it after its upload otherwise you have a file on your drive account you don't have the permissions to access.

Comment: before you ask have some more code for service account auth.   and My tutorial on service accounts so you understand the concept http://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-service-account/

Comment: Thanks a lot DalmTo i am able to upload, Open, Delete, and Download file content at server side using service account. Heads-up to your tutorial.

Comment: Thanks a lot DalmTo i am able to upload, Open, Delete, and Download file content at server side using service account. Heads-up to your tutorial. I am opening the file using the link "https://drive.google.com/file/d/item.Id/view?usp=drivesdk". Now what i want to do is to edit the document or want to open the document in edit mode can you let me know how can i do that. And it will save to the original  file.And not create the new file.

Comment: DalmTo can you help me in this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39960040/how-to-open-file-in-edit-mode-uploaded-to-google-drive-using-google-api-service

Comment: Thanks a lot DalmTo i completed with my task of Upload,View,Edit,Download and delete.One showstopper is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40012142/is-google-drive-api-has-any-paid-version-to-have-control-over-the-file-editor can you please look in to it