# How to open file in edit mode uploaded to google drive using google api service account

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I have google api service account.I successfully upload the file on the drive, open the file on browser.But i am not able to get the edit mode.How can i open a particular file in edit mode.And the changes will reflect to original files.
Currently i open the file using link "https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6TZcMlVILILeEN2al9KanZBS1k/view?usp=drivesdk" this does not support the edit mode. When the current user sign in on the above link page then i see the edit option but it saves to the current user logged in account and not reflect the original file.
You can try the above link its working now.
I am developing the application in asp.net MVC and using google api v2

Comment: You can you need to download the file making your changes then upload it again probably using patch instead of insert if I remember correctly.

Comment: Yes that's correct, any other way to open in edit mode directly in google docs.So user don't need to download and upload that.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to share the files to the users (depending on type in your use case). Once the file has been uploaded (thru Service Account), additional settings will be required to share the file. Set the role as `writer` and you'll be good to go (by calling the File's `selfLink`)